# Is "coupling" related only to code, or can the term be applied to software components and architecture?

Tags: separation-of-concerns, decoupling, coupling

For example, when discussing a build or deploy process, and making sure it is independent of the IDE. Is this "coupling", or is that considered Separation of Concerns, or something completely different? The general concept is to introduce the least number of variables into a process or architecture, so that when a failure occurs, the difficulty in identifying the possible points of failure are reduced significantly. Is there another definition for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something completely different.

Coupling is code.

Independent tools are just independent tools.

Microsoft has lead me to believe that independent tools are a bad idea.  They tell me that one vendor's integrated tool suite is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would characterise coupling as being something which relates to runtime system stability or system change.

When considering stability, coupling comes into the picture if the failure of one component causes the failure of other components. For example if two software components are communicating directly over a TCP connection, then the failure of one component means the other cannot do its work. The whole system is down. If I decouple by allowing the two components to communicate via a message queue (for example) then each component might continue to work independently in the absence of the other (assuming this makes sense in the application).

When considering system change, coupling comes into the picture when a code change in one module means I have to go and change code in a large number of other modules.

The example you give with build/deploy tools is a form of coupling, but not really what people have in mind when they consider architectural issues such as runtime and code coupling.